# Virtualbox Ubuntu Network Bridge auto create on machine start

Tags: 16.04, networking, virtualbox, startup

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 images

I follow [this tutorial](https://coderwall.com/p/2rpbba/docker-create-a-bridge-and-shared-network)

The last part, make the network permanent part does not work in my scenario.

> At this point, the network bridge will be detatched from eth1 if you
>   reboot the machine. So here are two more things to make the setting
>   permanent.
>
> Update `/etc/network/interfaces` like this:
>
> ```
> auto eth1 iface eth1 inet manual    
> pre-up ifconfig $IFACE up   
> post-down ifconfig $IFACE down
> ```
>
> And add the following command on `/etc/rc.local` (before exit 0):
>
> ```
> brctl addif docker1 eth1
> ```

After I reboot the machine, I can't ping the IP from my host. So I suspect is `rc.local` did not work.

I also tried to remove the `-e` parameter in `rc.local` file, but after reboot, still not working.

---

Next I try **solution 2**

Create a file `docker-network.sh` in directory `/etc/init.d`:

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo ip addr del 192.168.33.10/24 dev eth1
sudo brctl addif docker1 eth1
```

Make it executable:

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/docker-network.sh
```

Create symlinks for my script for various runlevels:

```
sudo update-rc.d docker-network.sh defaults
```

After I restart my virtual machine. I still can't ping direct to the machine.
However, after I SSH to the machine I run `/etc/init.d/docker-network.sh` then I am able to `ping` it.

So how do I make sure it able to run after I reboot?

**UPDATE**

I run `sudo systemctl enable rc-local.service` and restart. Then I run `sudo systemctl status rc-local`

```
vagrant@vagrant:~$ sudo systemctl status rc-local
● rc-local.service - /etc/rc.local Compatibility
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/rc-local.service; static; vendor preset:
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/rc-local.service.d
           └─debian.conf
   Active: active (exited) since Mon 2017-08-21 09:27:56 UTC; 10min ago
  Process: 1247 ExecStart=/etc/rc.local start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Tasks: 0
   Memory: 0B
      CPU: 0

Aug 21 09:27:56 vagrant systemd[1]: Starting /etc/rc.local Compatibility...
Aug 21 09:27:56 vagrant sudo[1259]:     root : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/ ; USER=root ;
Aug 21 09:27:56 vagrant sudo[1259]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for u
Aug 21 09:27:56 vagrant sudo[1308]:     root : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/ ; USER=root ;
Aug 21 09:27:56 vagrant sudo[1308]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for u
Aug 21 09:27:56 vagrant rc.local[1247]: bridge eth1 does not exist!
Aug 21 09:27:56 vagrant systemd[1]: Started /etc/rc.local Compatibility.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu is now turned into using `systemd` since started in Ubuntu 15.04 beta version and `rc.local` is "off" by default in 16.04.

You can enable `rc.local` by the following command and reboot your Ubuntu.

```
sudo systemctl enable rc-local.service
```

You would like to check the active status by the following command:

```
sudo systemctl status rc-local
```

Based on the line printed from above command result:

> Aug 21 09:27:56 vagrant rc.local[1247]: bridge eth1 does not exist

It means `rc.local` is triggered your script and it got executed but sometimes `rc.locsl` executing at *very first when booting* and it cause some interruption to be happen when executing the commands/script in your `rc.local`.

I suggest to put one `sleep x` before your command/script should run in `rc.local` (where `x` can specify value in seconds, may you need to increase this `x`seconds to see when it works), also you can do `sleep x` in your script before executing the main command.

Comment: @OP You may also need to have a look here [`How to Enable /etc/rc.local with Systemd`](https://www.linuxbabe.com/linux-server/how-to-enable-etcrc-local-with-systemd)

Comment: I updated more info in my question, is it means it is working, but my script not working?